# TextBox.Clear() or TextBox.Text = string.Empty

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there any difference between them? Thank you

```
TextBox.Clear();  
TextBox.Text = string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In practice: nope. Internally, there is. Both clear the text in completely different ways.

I wouldn't dare to tell you which one is better, but if you want to follow the sources, [here's for Clear()](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/TextBox.cs,200)  and [here's what it does when you change Text](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/TextBox.cs,1568)

Answer (score 1):

One important difference is that using `TextBox.Clear();` will clear the TextBox content, but it will keep any bindings intact.

If you use `TextBox.Text = string.Empty;`, any existing binding will be overridden.

For example, if you use Text binding like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Description}"></TextBox>
```

Then you must use the Clear() method. Otherwise, it will break your binding.

Answer (score -3):

--- Clear()

The Clear() method does more than just remove the text from the TextBox. It deletes all content and resets the text selection.

-- String.Empty

For some obscure reason string.Empty is not a constant. That means that in a number of cases where a compile-time constant is required, string.Empty isn't even legal. This includes case * blocks in switch statements, default values of optional parameters, parameters and properties in applying attributes, and a lot of other situations (left to the reader)*. So given that string.Empty is disallowed in some common situations.

Comment: The fact that `string.Empty` is not a constant doesn't have to do with the question at all (it's a `static readonly`). Setting `Text` to `string.Empty` -in practice- does delete all concrent and reset the selection aswell. It does so in a different way, yes, but it does the same